# DVWA is not accessible

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have configured [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/), but the tool is not accessible as it throws the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php:461 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\login.php(8): dvwaDatabaseConnect() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php on line 461

I have added `extension=php_mysql.dll` in the file `php.ini` that resides in location `C:\xampp\php`, but I still get the same error.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are using php v7, then you cannot enable the mysql extension because it has been removed from php 7.

Comment: i checked the version for php on xampp.it is PHP/7.0.2...so is there alternative option to run php? do i need upgrade php version first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment the version of your php 7.0.2. As php documentation on [mysql extension says](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php):

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Mysql extension should not be used, as the documentation states, you should use mysqli or PDO extension instead. If you have an application written in php that uses mysql extension and it is not feasible to quickly migrate it to mysqli or PDO, then you need to **downgrade** your php version because mysql extension is only included in earlier versions, not newer ones.

Comment: i have downgraded the version to 5.6.. so what command i should use now? "extension=php_mysqli.dll" or "PDO extension=php_mysql.dll"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question! 1) These are not commands, but config file options 2) I thought you wanted mysql extension, not mysqli or pdo. If you want to go along with either of the 2, then you need not have downgraded your php.

Comment: extension=php_mysql.dll is used to enable mysql extension right? for that,i believe php version need to be downgraded as per ur input..i have already downgraded the version from 7 to 5.6..now the command "extension=php_mysql.dll" should work..correct me if i am wrong anywhere

Comment: Again, these are not commands, just config line items. But yes, this should enable the mysql extension.